Cannot generate api keys for razorpay payment integration
I am not able to get API keys for razorpay. First they asked me for the website link and I did the kyc. But then I saw a article that said gwt the API keys without doing kyc. But then I did that too and they are not letting me go to the dashboard without doing kyc.
How can I get the api keys????
I tried creating my account without doing kyc because I saw an article that said try doing it without kyc.
But now they are not letting me go to the dashboard without kyc.

For issues with your service provider please contact your service provider.

To use the Razor pay API Key and Secret for website or APP
You need to publish the website (if website), or the app (iOS, Android) and provide the link in Business website details. Razor pay team will take 3-4 days to verify website.
Dashboard Image
